# How to search by facets with RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, faceted-search

I need to search documents, using RavenDB 3.0(for .NET), by name and also selected filters, like Price or Size.
Price and Size is facets.

I can't find any method to pass selected facets to query.

Is it possible to pass selected facets to query or I should do it manually by extending query?

Comment: Take a look on the docs page:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/indexes/querying/faceted-search#faceted-search